# Any way to speed up this PDO sql query?

Tags: php, sql, performance, pdo

I have this code which grabs multiple types of data from an sql db, and it's loading pretty slow. I was wondering if it's something I'm doing wrong that's making unnecessary querys or if there's nothing I can do to change it up. Here's the code.

(It wasn't showing all in the code boxes so I just uploaded it to pastebin. It's safe and used by many coders.)

http://pastebin.com/7p55rvz1

Thanks!

Comment: You're repeating the same query for each attribute you want to look up. Just do the query once, save the information in a variable, and then get all the attributes you need from that.

Comment: Actually I found out the querys take less then .5 seconds to load, it was the fact that it had to fetch the data from the query 25+ times that made it load so long. Going to try to add the data to an array and just call if from that array rather then doing the function stuff.

Comment: That was my point. Repeatedly loading the same data from the server will be slow.